# Add new associative element to each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I want to add key and value array multidimensional. I have 1 array multidimensional, like this:

```
$data = [
    ["name" => "albert","id"=>2101001,"value1"=>87 ,"value2"=>63,],
    ["name" => "andrew","id"=>2101002,"value1"=>76 ,"value2"=>79,],
];

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $a = $value['value1'];
    $b = $value['value2'];
    $data[$value]['average'] = ($a * 0.5) + ($b * 0.6) ;
    echo $value['average'];
}
```

When I run it in the browser, there is a warning message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal offset type in line $data[$value]['average'] = ($a * 0.5) + ($b * 0.6);

The result that I want is like this:

```
$dataresult = [
    ["name" => "albert", "id" => 2101001, "value1" => 87 , "value2" => 63, "average" => 81.3],
    ["name" => "andrew", "id" => 2101002, "value1" => 76 , "value2" => 79, "average" => 85.4],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to get the `$key` reference at the `foreach` loop to help index into the `data`:

```
$data = [
    ["name" => "albert","id"=>2101001,"value1"=>87 ,"value2"=>63,],
    ["name" => "andrew","id"=>2101002,"value1"=>76 ,"value2"=>79,],
   ];

   foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
       $a = $value['value1'];
       $b = $value['value2'];
       $data[$key]['average'] = ($a * 0.5) + ($b * 0.6) ;
       echo $value['average'];
   }

var_dump($data);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "albert"
    ["id"]=>
    int(2101001)
    ["value1"]=>
    int(87)
    ["value2"]=>
    int(63)
    ["average"]=>
    float(81.3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "andrew"
    ["id"]=>
    int(2101002)
    ["value1"]=>
    int(76)
    ["value2"]=>
    int(79)
    ["average"]=>
    float(85.4)
  }
}
```

PHP [fiddle example here](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/51db41ac52714aa0484dcecf997695ca/).

Answer (score 0):

Your script can be shortened syntactically by using array destructuring to declare the new `average` element in each row by reference.

Of course, your choice of associative key is questionable -- that's not how an average is calculated.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5Qatr))

```
foreach ($data as ['value1' => $v1, 'value2' => $v2, 'average' => &$avg]) {
    $avg = $v1 * 0.5 + $v2 * 0.6;
}
var_export($data);
```